# How to get Verizon WiFi Calling to work on new iPhone X

Tags: iphone, settings, setup, wifi-calling

I just activated an iPhone X on Verizon Wireless. My previous iPhone was able to do WiFi Calling on my home network.

Now when I try to turn WiFi Calling on (Settings -> Cellular -> Wi-Fi Calling), I get an error message telling me to contact Verizon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted my iPhone and was able to activate WiFi Calling with no issues.

Settings -> Cellular -> Wi-Fi Calling